# How do I run queryCommandState for a certain div (and not the whole page)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

How do I detect if an item is **bold**, ONLY within my **contenteditable** div, and not when the user clicks anywhere else on the entire page?

[Here's my JSFiddle with the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/annablabber/6Lbmdjty/1/)

I'm trying to run **document.queryCommandState("bold")** but only for my **contenteditable="true"** div.

I've googled for a while and can't find anything. I've tried replacing/adding my div selector **$(".text-editor")** to the word **document** in a few different ways, which doesn't work. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

---

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="text-editor">Content <b>editable</b>. Type here...</div>

<div class="normal-div">Content <b>not</b> editable.</div>

Click on the bold (and not bold) text in the two boxes. Result:
<div class="is-bold">The text your cursor's on is BOLD.</div>

<div class="is-not-bold">The text your cursor's on is NOT BOLD.</div>

<br>^^ I want this green result to only change when you're clicking inside the editable box.
```

CSS:

```
.text-editor {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.normal-div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.is-bold {
  display: none;
  color: green;
}

.is-not-bold {
  display: none;
  color: green;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var isItBold = document.queryCommandState("bold");
    if (isItBold == true) { 
    $(".is-bold").addClass("active");
    $(".is-not-bold").removeClass("active"); 
  }
  else { 
    $(".is-bold").removeClass("active");
    $(".is-not-bold").addClass("active"); 
  }
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `contenteditable` is being focused first, before doing any of that.

```
var editable = $("[contenteditable]")

setInterval(function () {
    if (!editable.is(":focus")) return

    var isItBold = document.queryCommandState("bold");
    if (isItBold == true) { 
    $(".is-bold").addClass("active");
    $(".is-not-bold").removeClass("active"); 
  }
  else { 
    $(".is-bold").removeClass("active");
    $(".is-not-bold").addClass("active"); 
  }
}, 100)
```

Also `setInterval` is not necessary here. You can bind on `click` event for example.